# Use JOIN instead of WHERE OR... IN sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there a better way to write the query below using JOIN?

```
SELECT
    t1.id
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    (
       t1.date1 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
    OR t1.date2 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
    OR t1.id2 IN (SELECT id FROM t2)
    OR t1.id3 IN (SELECT id FROM t2)
    OR t1.id4 IN (SELECT id FROM t2)
    );
```

Update: Only date2 can be `NULL`

Comment: Does it have to be a join, or are you just looking for ways to make the query more elegant?

Comment: @Mureinik Yes that is my original intention. But i really do mean "better" as faster regardless if it's elegant or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OR operations are probably going to mess with your speed the most, OR's kill index performance. 
This converts it to the most succinct join equivalent:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id IN (t1.id2, t1.id3, t1.id4)
WHERE t1.date1 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
    OR t1.date2 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
;
```

IN is logically an OR, but I think more recent MySQL versions have optimized it a bit; if not, this *might* have better performance:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM t1 
   LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2_2 ON t2_2.id  = t1.id2
   LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2_3 ON t2_3.id  = t1.id3
   LEFT JOIN t2 AS t2_4 ON t2_4.id  = t1.id4
WHERE (t1.date1 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
       OR t1.date2 >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
      )
      AND (t2_2.id IS NOT NULL OR t2_3.id IS NOT NULL OR t2_4.id IS NOT NULL)
;
```

It avoids the OR's on the id fields, so may take advantage of indexing on those fields; but JOINs three times as much, so could still end up being slower.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to use a `join` here, but if the intent is to make the query more elegant and/or easy to maintain, as hinted by the comments, there are several things you can do.

First, the date condition. Instead of repeating the same term twice, you can just check if the greatest of the dates is greater or equal to the given term - assuming that neither `date1` or `date2` can be `null`.

Second, the IDs condition. Instead of repeating the same term thrice you can use a single `exists` condition. I don't have a MySQL database handy to check it, but chances are it will actually run faster than your original version and not just look cleaner:

```
SELECT
    t1.id
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    GREATEST(t1.date1, t1.date2) >= (UTC_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL - 20 Hour)
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE id IN (t1.id2, t1.id3, t1.id4));
```

Comment: if `date1` or `date2` can be NULL, this will not be equivalent to the original.

Comment: @spencer7593 good catch! I added a clarifying comment to my answer.